# C++: How to recursively/iteratively search HTML file (using Boost C++)?

Tags: html, c++, xml, boost, iteration

I'm working on an application where I need to fetch a HTML file (from the web) and obtain a piece of information, by searching for a string.

I reckon it is more effective and easier to treat the HTML file as a XML file and iterate over the tags in the HTML file and match the content with a string.

Here is the HTML table I'm interested in:

```
<table width='100%' class='datatable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td width='30px'>
    </td>
    <td width='220px'>
    </td>
    <td width='50px'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height='7' colspan='4'>
      <img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='170'>
      Aktiv tid: <!--This is a string I will search for.-->
    </td>
    <td colspan='3'>
      1 dag, 17:03:46 <!--This is a piece of information I need to obtain.-->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height='7' colspan='4'>
      <img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='170'>
      Bandbredd (upp/ned) [kbps/kbps]:
    </td>
    <td colspan='3'>
      1.058 / 21.373
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height='7' colspan='4'>
      <img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='170'>
      Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]: <!--This is another string I will search for.-->
    </td>
    <td colspan='3'>
      1,67 / 42,95 <!--This is another piece of information I need to obtain.-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So I will search for the `<td>` tags containing either of the following strings:

- Aktiv tid:
- Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]:

After that I need to select the next `<td>` tag containing the piece of information I want (in the same `<tr>`.

I successfully fetched the HTML file using cURL but need a little help with the XML search algorithm.

Thank you in advance!

(**EDIT**: Here is the pseudocode for my desired application (should be very self-explanatory):

```
extern "C" {
    #include "url.h"
}

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string xmlSearch(std::string fn, std::string str);

int main(void)
{
    /* download HTML file from URL to file */
    url("http://myurl.com/","page.html");

    /* search page.html for "Aktiv tid:" and return the content of the next <td> tag. */
    std::string data0 = xmlSearch("page.html","Aktiv tid:");

    /* search page.html for "Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]:" and return the content of the next <td> tag. */
    std::string data1 = xmlSearch("page.html","Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]:");

    /* process results */
}

std::string xmlSearch(std::string fn, std::string str){
    /* perform search algorithim */

    /* return content of the next <td> tag. */
}
```

)

Comment: @MSalters I changed the title, hopefully it isn't as confusing now.

Comment: Take a look at [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). [There are libraries for C++](http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/HomePage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see myself doing this with a quick-and-dirty script, not with C++, really.

In one line:

```
(tidy -asxml input.xml | xmllint --xpath 'descendant-or-self::*[starts-with(text(), "Aktiv tid:")]/following-sibling::*/text()' -) 2>/dev/null
```

Here

- `tidy` converts quirky html to xml
- `xmllint` queries it:

  - from `*` (any element) which `[starts-with(text(), "Aktiv tid:")]`
  - select the `text()` from the following sibling
- `2>/dev/null` is there to suppress any warning from `tidy` and `xmllint`

Presto, it prints:

```
1 dag, 17:03:46
```

For the precise input from your question.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need, I assume this can be adapted to be called from C++? Or even creating a separate application for downloading the HTML file from an URL with cURL and then run a program to process it and use the output of the command as a command line argument to the program. What do you reckon is the best way?

Comment: @Linus Like I said, _I could see myself doing this with a quick-and-dirty script, not with C++_. So, yeah, make it a separate script to get the input

Comment: Okay thanks, where can I download `tidy` and `xmlint`?

Comment: I do `apt-get install tidy libxml2-utils`. But there are other tools (xmlstarlet? etc.)